# How to check iPhone Camera is fake or original

Tags: iphone

I've two iPhone 6s Plus in space gray color, and both has different camera style. I thought one of them might be fake, but when I saw 6s Plus pictures on [Gsmarena](https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_6s_plus-pictures-7243.php), it is also showing different styles. Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between them.

Actually my both phones are dead due to board issue, and I wanna buy used 6s Plus. For this I want to know that apple made different camera styles or one of them is fake, so I can buy a real phone.

[image]

Below screenshot is from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/SP727/SP727-iphone6s-plus-gray-select-2015.png)

[image]

Below picture is of my phones, both has same color but different camera style.

[image]

Below is zoom picture of first two images google.

[image]

Comment: @Mark please see camera lens holder color on these images

Comment: @nohillside actually I want to know that apple made different camera style or one of them is fake, so I can buy real phone if one is not original.

Comment: The colour matches the case

Comment: @Mark, but I have both phone of same colour and their camera style is not same. Any idea why?